# How can I remove this line?

Tags: fancyhdr

[image: line]

How can I remove this line? (The line above the section)
I use `\pagestyle{fancy}`. Is it because of this?

Comment: Unless you show the code that's giving rise to the screenshot you've posted, it'll be very difficult to provide a clean dianosis, let alone suggest a viable cure.

Comment: Type `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` before `\begin{document}`

Comment: also please don't use that nonsensical `afin` word, at least you can use `ilgin`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Why shouldnt I use afin? Its turkish so I have to.

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided minimal working example. But probably it is a problem related to headers. Try adding this in your preamble.

```
   \usepackage{fancyhdr}
   \pagestyle{plain}
```

Comment: Well, why loading `fancyhdr` to begin with?